# delphi create opc connection to plc

Tags: delphi, plc, opc

i would like to connect from a delphi application to a plc. for a test i just created a opcconnect, a opcgroup and a opcimage item to see two different images
when i change the value of the address from 0 to 1. So far it doesn't work and i don't know why, could anyone help me?

is there a good example for how to connect to a plc with opc?

thanks..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [OPC Programming with Delphi](http://www.opcconnect.com/delphi.php) has lots of useful information. Asking for examples is off-topic here though.

Comment: oh i am sorry... but thank you